# Ping strange behavior

Tags: networking, dns, ping

i have a strange behavior when I ping, the response alternates between IP and dns record
why this difference?
(I've anonymized the IP and my target DNS record)

```bash
ping google.com
PING google.com (10.10.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=13.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=12.2 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=16.1 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=54 time=15.0 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=8 ttl=54 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=9 ttl=54 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=54 time=12.5 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=11 ttl=54 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=54 time=13.2 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=13 ttl=54 time=17.6 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=14 ttl=54 time=13.3 ms
64 bytes from google.com (10.10.10.1): icmp_seq=15 ttl=54 time=11.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=54 time=19.2 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=54 time=13.1 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 17 received, 0% packet loss, time 16020ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.505/13.892/19.262/2.047 ms
```

this seems to be a DNS interruption problem
How can I go further in the analysis and catch the error?
When I use dig, I always manage to do the resolution